# Overflow of HTML5 <input> tag using datalist in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-datalist

I have a HTML page at http://codepen.io/liang179/pen/WQvERK contain a  tag associated with a large datalist. It display in chrome has a overflow.There still have data out of screen.but It is fine in firefox with scroll bar.
What can I do to make it display in chrome with scroll bar like in firefox.
Below is the code.

```js
$('#trigger').click(function(){
  $class = "animated infinite " + $('#type').val();
  $('#target').removeClass().addClass($class);
});
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
 <div id='target' style="margin: 200px auto; width: 200px; height:200px; background-color:#663399"></div>
 <div>
  <input id="type" list="classes">
  <datalist id="classes">
   <option value="bounce">
   <option value="flash">
   <option value="pulse">
   <option value="rubberBand">
   <option value="shake">
   <option value="swing">
   <option value="tada">
   <option value="wobble">
   <option value="jello">
   <option value="bounceIn">
   <option value="bounceInDown">
   <option value="bounceInLeft">
   <option value="bounceInRight">
   <option value="bounceInUp">
   <option value="bounceOut">
   <option value="bounceOutDown">
   <option value="bounceOutLeft">
   <option value="bounceOutRight">
   <option value="bounceOutUp">
   <option value="fadeIn">
   <option value="fadeInDown">
   <option value="fadeInDownBig">
   <option value="fadeInLeft">
   <option value="fadeInLeftBig">
   <option value="fadeInRight">
   <option value="fadeInRightBig">
   <option value="fadeInUp">
   <option value="fadeInUpBig">
   <option value="fadeOut">
   <option value="fadeOutDown">
   <option value="fadeOutDownBig">
   <option value="fadeOutLeft">
   <option value="fadeOutLeftBig">
   <option value="fadeOutRight">
   <option value="fadeOutRightBig">
   <option value="fadeOutUp">
   <option value="fadeOutUpBig">
   <option value="flipInX">
   <option value="flipInY">
   <option value="flipOutX">
   <option value="flipOutY">
   <option value="lightSpeedIn">
   <option value="lightSpeedOut">
   <option value="rotateIn">
   <option value="rotateInDownLeft">
   <option value="rotateInDownRight">
   <option value="rotateInUpLeft">
   <option value="rotateInUpRight">
   <option value="rotateOut">
   <option value="rotateOutDownLeft">
   <option value="rotateOutDownRight">
   <option value="rotateOutUpLeft">
   <option value="rotateOutUpRight">
   <option value="hinge">
   <option value="rollIn">
   <option value="rollOut">
   <option value="zoomIn">
   <option value="zoomInDown">
   <option value="zoomInLeft">
   <option value="zoomInRight">
   <option value="zoomInUp">
   <option value="zoomOut">
   <option value="zoomOutDown">
   <option value="zoomOutLeft">
   <option value="zoomOutRight">
   <option value="zoomOutUp">
   <option value="slideInDown">
   <option value="slideInLeft">
   <option value="slideInRight">
   <option value="slideInUp">
   <option value="slideOutDown">
   <option value="slideOutLeft">
   <option value="slideOutRight">
   <option value="slideOutUp">
  </datalist>
  <button id="trigger">Trigger</button>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am also facing this problem. I need a scrollbar for html5 datalist input.

Comment: Chrome's datalist support is crap. It just renders the list straight off your screen without providing a scroll bar. If the list is too long it crashes Desktop Window Manager on Windows. It only provided results that start with, rather than contains the text that was typed. It's completely unusable as far as I am concerned. Mozilla's behavior is exactly what any sane individual would expect. There are several bug reports open for these issues, but don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 2):

There is a ticket for this bug on the Chromium bug tracker, open since 2014. Some recent comments indicate that it may get prioritized in early 2017.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375637

> Comment 65 by zkoch@…um.org, Sep 16 2016
>
> […] I'll try to get this prioritized in early 2017.
>
> Comment 69 by rbyers@…um.org, Mar 23 2017
>
> The predictability program is reviewing the top 50 starred Blink bugs
> this quarter, and this is #46 on that list.  We’re hoping that for each
> we can either close it, set an owner and target milestone, or set a
> NextAction date so that we know when to check back in.

---

**Update:** a comment from Apr 17, 2018 indicates that a fix was released:

> Comment 91 by lonnie…@…rt.com, Apr 17
>
> I'd like to add thanks for this also. The implementation of the scroll
> bar looks really nice in Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Yet the ticket is still open (as of May 2018) due to some bugs discovered in Windows 10. It has been merged into ticket [#773041](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=773041).

Comment: Please add the relevant part of the link you provided to your answer in case the link goes dead